# Connect points with horizontal lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

The goal is to fill the space between two arrays `y1` and `y2`, similar to matplotlib's [fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html). But I don't want to fill the space with a polygon (for example with `hatch='|'`), but rather I want to draw the vertical lines only between the data points of the two arrays.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 10
y1 = np.random.random(n)
y2 = np.random.random(n) + 1
x1 = np.arange(n)
ax.fill_between(x1, y1, y2, facecolor='w', hatch='|')
```

[image: matplotlib fill_between]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a LineCollection could be handy if there are lots of lines in the game. Similar to the other answer, but less expensive:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

def draw_lines_between(*, x1=None, x2=None, y1, y2, ax=None, **kwargs):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    x1 = x1 if x1 is not None else np.arange(len(y1))
    x2 = x2 if x2 is not None else x1

    cl = LineCollection(np.stack((np.c_[x1, x2], np.c_[y1, y2]), axis=2), **kwargs)
    ax.add_collection(cl)
    return cl

n = 10
y1 = np.random.random(n)
y2 = np.random.random(n) + 1
x = np.arange(n)
color_list = [str(x) for x in np.round(np.linspace(0., 0.8, n), 2)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1, 'r')
ax.plot(x, y2, 'b')
draw_lines_between(ax=ax, x1=x, y1=y1, y2=y2, colors=color_list)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi I tried this for a plot that I made similar to something above (I used plt.scatter) and the line that is drawn between the two points extends all the way from the top of the figure. Also I noticed that some dots aren't connected by a line. Is there a way to only have the line in between two points and connect all dots? (figure is here -> https://imgur.com/a/bb5HCxC) If this needs to be discussed elsewhere please let me know. I can provide relevant code if need be.

Comment: @EliTurasky You can edit [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59988357/4124317) with a [mcve], i.e. runnable example and ask for the problem. Ping me once that is done so it can be reopened

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide a runnable example as my code involves dataframes and outside data. I can update my question with the data I am using though.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little function which takes two arrays `y1`, `y2` (`x1`, `x2` are optional)
and connects their data points *vertically*.

```py
def draw_lines_between(*, ax, x1=None, x2=None, y1, y2, color_list=None, **kwargs):
    assert len(y1) == len(y2)
    assert isinstance(color_list, list)

    n = len(y1)
    if x1 is None:
        x1 = np.arange(n)
    if x2 is None:
        x2 = x1

    if color_list is None:
        color_list = [None for i in range(n)]
    elif len(color_list) < n:
        color_list = [color_list] * n

    h = np.zeros(n, dtype=object)
    for i in range(n):
        h[i] = ax.plot((x1[i], x2[i]), (y1[i], y2[i]), color=color_list[i], **kwargs)[0]

    return h


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 10
y1 = np.random.random(n)
y2 = np.random.random(n) + 1
x1 = np.arange(n)
color_list = [str(x) for x in np.round(np.linspace(0., 0.8, n), 2)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, y1, 'r')
ax.plot(x1, y2, 'b')
draw_lines_between(ax=ax, x1=x1, y1=y1, y2=y2, color_list=color_list)
```

[image: Draw lines between lines]